# Como ler ou executar outros arquivos e programas com Lua?

Tags: lua

Tem algum `file system(fs)` em Lua? Alguma forma de executar arquivos JS em Lua?

Comment: Talvez isso te ajude: https://github.com/ceifa/demoon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem e não tem. Existe o `os.execute()` que faz o mesmo.

[Documentação](https://www.lua.org/pil/22.2.html). [Wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/OsLibraryTutorial).

Ele não serve para executar arquivos JavaScript, mas pode chamar o Node ou Deno que fará essa execução.

Pode haver outra solução mais adequada dependendo da real e especifica necessidade.

Comment: mas eu consigo pegar algo que o node retornar?

Comment: Ele vai retornar se deu certo ou não, só isso. Se quer fazer comunicação terá que criar um mecanismo próprio, igual o `system`.